# what would be synonym of 'utility' in the sense of 'marginal-gain'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I wanted to ask, what would be synonym of *utility*, when it is used in the sense of *marginal-gain*. For example, we say:

> Among two competing persons, I prefer giving this object to Person-A, since Person-A has a higher utility of using this object than Person-B".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps **advantage** or **capability** would work.

Comment: Thanks, but I look for more closer answer.

Comment: @user984260: if this isn't what you're looking for, can you give more description as to why this isn't good, and what extra you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Hrm... These are all economics terms, so `utility` used in that quite narrow context does work. You could also consider, simply, `value`.